# Soundcloud API request limit

Tags: soundcloud

I would like to create an app using soundcloud's API to play music. I read on your API terms of use that you have a limit of 15000 requests per day. I also saw that some apps (Musify for example) exceed this limit. 
So is it possible to exceed the limit and if so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to work something out with Soundcloud directly, but I wouldn't bank on it.

Keep in mind that embeded tracks [do not](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/limits) count towards the the 15,000 limit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ThéoFleismaher you're welcome! Please click the green check mark next to it if you're satisfied :)